# React - map using multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, sorry if this is too basic.

I have an array:

```
const previews  = this.state.previews;
```

structured like so:

```
previews: [
"https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/86319eaef2091a7f89e53f133ad8d76025e50c4b?cid=d3b2f7a12362468daa393cf457185973",
"https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/e5a194941e4268f3861439567b1b5700b6060732?cid=d3b2f7a12362468daa393cf457185973",
]
```

which I'm mapping in order to render each one of its values, like so:

```
return (
   <div id="parent">
    {previews.map((preview, index) =>
      <span key={index}>
        <Media>
          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-player">
              <Player src={preview} />
            </div>
            <div className="media-controls">
              <PlayPause />
              <CurrentTime />
              <Progress />
              <Duration />
              <MuteUnmute />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Media>
      </span>)
    }
  </div>
);
```

The above works. But lets say I have another array (of corresponding artists for each preview):

```
const artists  = this.state.artists;
```

structured like so:

```
artists: [
"The Milk Carton Kids",
"Yo La Tengo",
]
```

and I want to include this array in the mapping, in order to render each artist as well, like so:

```
return (
      (...)

      <td class="number">{ artist }</td>

      (...)
);
```

How do map this second array using `map()` in the code above?

Do I have to create another object with nested arrays?

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: You'd like a list of `artists` data to be rendered after the first list of `preview` data?

Comment: I'd like to render each artist alongside with its own preview value. does it make sense?

Comment: I see, so each `artist` has a corresponding item in the `preview` array?

Comment: yes, precisely, they are ordered.

Comment: Can you show some example data on previews and artists?

Comment: sure. please refer to edit.

Comment: So, previews are a part of the artists? It's confusing. Can you check the answer I posted and see if that's what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by 'part of'. They are two separate arrays, but previews[0] should go along with artists[0], and so on. they are ordered.

Comment: Oh Okay I understood that artist has a property called previews which is also an array. Anyway I see that you got you solution. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use the second `index` parameter passed to your `map` callback, to access the item of the `previews` array that corresponds to the current `artist` item being mapped as follows:

```
render() {
    const { artists, previews } = this.state;

    return (<>
    { 
      artists.map((artist, index) => {
        /* 
        Obtain preview from state.previews for current artist index 
        */
        const preview = previews[index];

        /* 
        Render current artist data, and corresponding preview data
        for the current artist 
        */
        return (<span key={index}> 
                  <span class="number">{ artist }</span>
                  <Media>
                    <div className="media">
                      <div className="media-player">
                        <Player src={preview} />
                      </div>
                      <div className="media-controls">
                        <PlayPause />
                        <CurrentTime />
                        <Progress />
                        <Duration />
                        <MuteUnmute />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Media>
                </span>)
       })
     }
     </>)   
}
```

Comment: I know your answer is cleaner than my code as is, but could you please keep the structure with the anchors depicted in the question?

Comment: Sure - is it safe to assume that the `previewUrl` should be passed to `<Player />` ?

Comment: you're welcome - I just added a span (instead of td) to show how this can be achieved (note that td must be a child of a tr in a table which is why I've used span instead)

Comment: this works, thaks a lot. but this `return <>` syntax is a bit funny, and its closure changes code color to yellow, albeit throwing no errors. is this expected?

Comment: you're welcome - the map callback introduces a local closure, but I'm not aware of what the yellow is that you're seeing. What editor are you using?

Comment: sublime text. white closure `{}` turns to yellow after `return <>` closure ... `</>`, with or without `()`. But it all works and no syntax error is thrown.

Comment: Interesting - I used vscode and don't have that kind of syntax highlighting with my current setup. The `<>` is short-hand for a fragment, which basically allows an "array of JSX elements" to be rendered from a component without explicitly wrapping those elements in a div (or some other container)